# NextJS/Firebase - implementing firebase analytics throw error: Missing App configuration value

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-analytics

i am using Next JS 13 with default pages directory and i use database for my project. Everything works fine, until i started to implementing firebase analytics.

First it throwed that window is undefiend. I solved it by checking window. After that it worked so i wanted to test logEvent() function in my index.js page.

And it throw **FirebaseError: Installations: Missing App configuration value: "projectId" (installations/missing-app-config-values).**

I tried to use proccess.env.NEXT_PUBLIC but it didnt worked.

```
import { initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';
import { getAnalytics } from 'firebase/analytics';


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
export const analytics = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? getAnalytics(app) : null;
export default app;
```

Index.js example

```
<Button
key={`${name}_${index}`}
href={url}
mouseEnter={() => selectedImg !== img && handleMouseEnter(img)}
customStyles={'py-5 bg-primary-blue/60'}
onClick={() => (analytics ? logEvent(analytics, name) : {})}
>  Test </Button>
```

Have someone similiar problem and solved it?

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, the 'appId' is missing in your config object. You could try to [copy](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592#zippy=%2Cin-this-article:%7E:text=Get%20config%20object%20for%20your%20web%20app) it again in the Firebase Console to make sure you're using the updated one.

Comment: well it works when i use hardcoded values instead of proccess.env so there must be some behaviour in next js app

Comment: Oh i see now, i created .env file but in next js env should be inside next-config.js

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED: There was problem that i was using .env file, but in next js env variables should be inside next.config so it will load during build time.**